# Deleting rows before a date with datetime-field

Tags: mysql, date, delete-row

I'm trying to delete users that are older than a certain date in wordpress.

Locally this works (but not on production server where the mysql is newer).

```
SELECT ID FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_registered < 20131201
```

The user_registered is a datetime-field. A field could look like this: `2013-12-10 21:20:12`

Is this above way it's supposed to be done? Or is there a better solution? I'm asking because I'm getting results that isn't really satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the date format you use is the issue, try this :

```
SELECT ID FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_registered < '2013-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_registered < str_to_date('20131201', '%Y/%m/%d')
```